# How would I model an email marketing graph in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am really drawn (and new) to neo4j as a way to model my data for easier analysis.  Part of my job requires that I analyze our email marketing efforts.

As a simple data model, I think of my graph as having 3 nodes:

1. `Lead` - the customer in the database
2. `Email` - the email sent to the customer(s)
3. `URL` - a link contained in an email

With the relationships being:

1. `(Lead) -[:SENT]-> (Email)`
2. `(Lead) -[:OPEN]-> (Email)`
3. `(Lead) -[:CLICKED_THRU]-> (Email)`
4. `(EMAIL) -[:CONTAINS]-> (URL)`

Now to my question.  Using the data model I constructed above, how can I isolate the URLs that a Lead has clicked on.  If I add another relationship `(Lead) -[:CLICKED_ON]-> (URL)`, I do not know which email the URL was contained in (we send the same URL in multiple emails).

Right now, I have a traditional RDBMS implementation, where I know which lead clicked on which URLs from each email.

I want to try to learn neo4j using this business problem, but I am struggling as to how to relate the URL that was clicked on to the specific email.

Thanks in advance for any help.  If this is not the proper forum, please let me know where I can direct my question.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with the model as you have it, is that in order for it to work you must assume that each email has one and only one link.  That may not generally be true.

Now, *if it is true* that every email has only one link, then you could do what you wanted to this way:

`MATCH (l:Lead)-[:CLICKED_THRU]->(e:Email)->[:CONTAINS]->(url:URL)
 return l, url`

This would tell you who clicked on which URL.   But notice that if there's more than one URL per email, this would make it look like every user who ever clicked on an email link clicked on *every link* in that email.

A better way to model your data would be like this:

`(Lead)-[:CLICKED_THRU]->(URL)
(EMAIL)-[:CONTAINS]->(URL)
(Lead)-[:OPEN]->(Email)`

This would let you ask which URLs were clicked (just by following `CLICKED_THRU` but it would also tell you which emails were opened.  Also, if URLs are unique to emails, by following the connection `:CONTAINS` you could know which email was opened by which link was clicked.

Finally, for general modeling concerns in neo4j, make sure to [check out this presentation](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/modeling) which goes into depth on how to think about modeling, and how it's different than relational.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct, the same URL can be in multiple emails.  My aim was to take keep the data as-is out of my CRM, but it sounds like I need to think about creating a unique URL (through transformation) or leverage a Hyper Edge

Comment: If your CRM stores this as you've modeled it now, I don't see how the CRM differentiates between links in an email.  On the other hand if links, emails, and leads are all individual tables with PK/FK links, you can turn any PK/FK link into a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that at the point the URL is accessed you know which email it was from, that an E-Mail contains multiple URLs and that the same URLs may be present in multiple emails. You may want to model a hyper edge (something that links together more than two nodes) as a node:

`(Lead)-[:CLICKED_URL_FROM]->(EmailLinkNode)`
 `(EmailLinkNode)-[:FROM_EMAIL]->(email)`
 `(EmailLinkNode)-[:CLICKED_URL]->(url)`

I think that this is the only way to relate three Nodes in a single 'relationship', but I am quite new to this myself.

Something similar is described on the [NeoTechnology page here](http://www.neotechnology.com/neo4j-modeling-hyper-edges-property-graph/).

I guess considering your data you could consider also think of creating a new Node to represent the concept of an EmailUrl which is a dummy node used to uniquely identify a url when related to a specific email.

`(email)-[:CONTAINS]->(EmailUrl)-[:FOR_URL]->(url)`

This leads to a simple relationship between the lead and the now unique node (lead)-[:CLICKED_THRU]->(EmailUrl) and therefore simple queries to find out not only which urls were clicked, but which emails proved the most enticing to your leads.